# Trigger CI/CD pipeline job after merge to specific branch. Not when merge request is created

Tags: continuous-integration, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I know you can set it up so that the job only executes when there is a merge request to a specific branch but I don't want it to execute when the merge request is created, I want it to execute when the merge request is actually merged. I currently have it like this:

```
rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master"'
```

But as I said this is not what I want. I also tried this:

```
rules:
    - if: '$CI_MERGE_REQUEST_TARGET_BRANCH_NAME == "master" && $CI_MERGE_REQUEST_APPROVED'
```

This did not work either. I know it is possible using the [only](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#:%7E:text=only%20and%20except%20are%20not%20being%20actively%20developed.%20rules%20is%20the%20preferred%20keyword%20to%20control%20when%20to%20add%20jobs%20to%20pipelines.) keyword but I cannot use only I need to use rules. Would love some insight!

Comment: Isn't that the same as triggering on a commit to the target branch?

Comment: It is but I do not want it to trigger on every commit just the commit from the merge request.